# How to detect or check whether a Poly Line was Inside Another Poly Line or Overlap with Other Poly Line Using Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, gwt, google-maps-api-3

I was using Google Maps Javascript API (GWT Maps V3 API) to some poly line in Google Maps. There are some poly line that overlap each other like in this picture: 
[image: Two Poly Line overlap]

As we can see from the picture above, there are two poly line blue and purple that overlap each other (they have the same path). Then add a red poly line among those two poly line like this: 
[image: Three poly line overlap]

Now I need to get all poly line that overlap / intersect with the red poly line. Is there any way I could do this in Google Maps Javascript API? Any comment and answer will be appreciated. Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#poly)

isLocationOnEdge(point:LatLng, poly:Polygon|Polyline, tolerance?:number)

> To determine whether a point falls on or near a polyline, or on or
>   near the edge of a polygon, pass the point, the polyline/polygon, and
>   optionally a tolerance value in degrees to
>   google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(). The function returns
>   true if the distance between the point and the closest point on the
>   line or edge falls within the specified tolerance. The default
>   tolerance value is 10-9 degrees.